# Change the direction of a Brace

Tags: tikz-pgf, implicit-braces

The first of my two braces (the one on the left does not appear as expected. How can I make it head downwards?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}




    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
    %\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}



    \node (rect) at (2.25,0.5) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1cm] {A};
    \node (rect2) at (3.25,0.5) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.9cm,minimum height=1cm] {};


    \node (rect3) at (5.25,2) [draw,dashed,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1cm] {A};
    \node (rect4) at (5.95,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.35cm,minimum height=1cm,label = south:{B}] {};
    \node (rect5) at (6.45,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.2cm,minimum height=1cm,label = south:{C}] {};
    \draw [thick,->] (rect2)-- (rect3);


    \node (rect6) at (5.25,0) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1cm] {A};
    \node (rect7) at (5.95,0) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.35cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
    \node (rect8) at (6.45,0) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.2cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
    \draw [thick,->] (rect2)--(rect6) ;

    \node (rect9) at (5.45,-2) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.85cm,minimum height=1cm] {A'};
    \node (rect10) at (6.1,-2) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.2cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
    \draw[thick,->] (rect2)--(rect9);

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (rect4.north west) -- (rect5.north east); 

    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,raise=2pt}] (rect.south west) -- (rect2.south east); 



    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Worst case of Algorithm 1. Factorial time}
    \label{fig:6forces}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `mirror` in

```
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,raise=2pt,mirror}] (rect.south west) 
                -- (rect2.south east);
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (rect) at (2.25,0.5) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1cm] {A};
\node (rect2) at (3.25,0.5) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.9cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
\node (rect3) at (5.25,2) [draw,dashed,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1cm] {A};
\node (rect4) at (5.95,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.35cm,minimum height=1cm,label = south:{B}] {};
\node (rect5) at (6.45,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.2cm,minimum height=1cm,label = south:{C}] {};
\draw [thick,->] (rect2)-- (rect3);


\node (rect6) at (5.25,0) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1cm] {A};
\node (rect7) at (5.95,0) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.35cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
\node (rect8) at (6.45,0) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.2cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
\draw [thick,->] (rect2)--(rect6) ;

\node (rect9) at (5.45,-2) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.85cm,minimum height=1cm] {A'};
\node (rect10) at (6.1,-2) [draw,thick,minimum width=0.2cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
\draw[thick,->] (rect2)--(rect9);

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (rect4.north west) -- (rect5.north east);

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,raise=2pt,mirror}] (rect.south west) -- (rect2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Worst case of Algorithm 1. Factorial time}
\label{fig:6forces}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]